# ElasticSearch wrongly halting indexing because of supposedly low disk free space

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a very simple ES6 install with a single node, on a big-enough (for my needs) disk:

```
root@ip-172-17-20-222:/home/admin# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  155M  1.4G  10% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1   59G   34G   24G  59% /
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
```

As you can see, there is plenty of free space on the disk.

I configured ES using it's http API:

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json"  "http://172.17.20.222:9200/_cluster/settings" -d'
{
  "transient": {
    "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.low": "85%",
    "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high": "90%",
    "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.flood_stage": "95%",
    "cluster.info.update.interval": "1m"
  }
}'
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://172.17.20.222:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'
```

But just a few minutes later:

```
[2019-11-22T16:02:46,889][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [C25At0X] low disk watermark [85%] exceeded on [C25At0XLRAyaZ00zegY20A][C25At0X][/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0] free: 6gb[10.2%], replicas will not be assigned to this node
[2019-11-22T16:03:46,890][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [C25At0X] flood stage disk watermark [95%] exceeded on [C25At0XLRAyaZ00zegY20A][C25At0X][/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0] free: 2.6gb[4.4%], all indices on this node will be marked read-only
[2019-11-22T16:04:46,892][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [C25At0X] flood stage disk watermark [95%] exceeded on [C25At0XLRAyaZ00zegY20A][C25At0X][/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0] free: 2.5gb[4.3%], all indices on this node will be marked read-only
[2019-11-22T16:05:46,897][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [C25At0X] flood stage disk watermark [95%] exceeded on [C25At0XLRAyaZ00zegY20A][C25At0X][/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0] free: 2.5gb[4.2%], all indices on this node will be marked read-only
[2019-11-22T16:06:46,899][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [C25At0X] flood stage disk watermark [95%] exceeded on [C25At0XLRAyaZ00zegY20A][C25At0X][/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0] free: 2.4gb[4.1%], all indices on this node will be marked read-only
[2019-11-22T16:07:46,901][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [C25At0X] flood stage disk watermark [95%] exceeded on [C25At0XLRAyaZ00zegY20A][C25At0X][/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0] free: 2.3gb[4%], all indices on this node will be marked read-only
[2019-11-22T16:08:46,903][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [C25At0X] flood stage disk watermark [95%] exceeded on [C25At0XLRAyaZ00zegY20A][C25At0X][/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0] free: 2.3gb[3.9%], all indices on this node will be marked read-only
[2019-11-22T16:09:46,905][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [C25At0X] flood stage disk watermark [95%] exceeded on [C25At0XLRAyaZ00zegY20A][C25At0X][/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0] free: 2.2gb[3.8%], all indices on this node will be marked read-only
[2019-11-22T16:10:46,908][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [C25At0X] rerouting shards: [one or more nodes has gone under the high or low watermark]
```

If I understand correctly, ES is halting the indexing because it believes that there is not enough free space left in my disk, but this doesn't seem to be correct.

I don't believe the problem is inodes-related either, as per:

```
root@ip-172-17-20-222:/home/admin# ulimit
unlimited
root@ip-172-17-20-222:/home/admin# df -ih
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev             2.0M   269  2.0M    1% /dev
tmpfs            2.0M   683  2.0M    1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1   3.8M   44K  3.8M    2% /
tmpfs            2.0M     1  2.0M    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            2.0M     2  2.0M    1% /run/lock
tmpfs            2.0M    15  2.0M    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            2.0M    11  2.0M    1% /run/user/1000
```

What else could be causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

> `free: 2.5gb[4.3%]`

These numbers are coming from the same source as `df`, but can change quite quickly. It looks like something is consuming about 100MB more disk space every minute. You will need to track your disk usage as it changes over time to catch this happening with `df` too.